# Selenium WebDriver to match similar xpaths

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I have following xpaths, which should be handled on same way by WebDriver, I need to get text content from these.

```
//*[@id="dialogMessage"]/div[3]
//*[@id="dialogMessage"]/div[3]/p
//*[@id="dialogMessage"]/div[3]/p/span[2]
```

I tried to use this code to match all of the above ones.

```
String result_text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@value, 'dialogMessage')]")).getText();
```

Only one of these xpaths is present on page in each page loads. I get following error message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//id[contains(@value, 'dialogMessage')]"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to get all elements that contain attribute value equals to dialogMessage instead try using this xpath:

```
//*[contains(@id, 'dialogMessage')]
```

or

```
 //*[@id='dialogMessage']
```

Comment: ...or better yet, use `driver.findElement(By.id("dialogMessage"));`.